# Lambda expression C# failed to convert to the object type and fail with ref

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Have such function:

```
   private static void EncodeString(ref string str)
    {
        using (RLE inst_rle = new RLE())
        {
            string str_encoded = inst_rle.Encode(ref str);
            Console.WriteLine(

              "\r\nBase string ({0} chars): {1}\r\nAfter RLE-encoding ({2} chars): {3}\r\nCompression percentage: %{4}",
              str.Length, str, str_encoded.Length, str_encoded,
              () => { (100 * (str.Length - str.encoded.Length) / str.Length); }

                             );
        }
    }
```

As I remember it's a style of lambdas in C#: () => { < action > ; }

But getting such errors:

- *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it*
- *Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*
- *Cannot use ref or out parameter 'str' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression*
- *Cannot use ref or out parameter 'str' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression*

***How to use Lambda in C# EXACLTY in my app (console app) without explicity using***

***Delegate / Func< T >, like in `() => { }` way?***

Comment: FYI, I don't think any of the answers have picked up that you can't use your `str` parameter in any of the lambdas. As `str` is marked with `ref`, you can't use it in the lambda. You would have to store it as a local temporary variable first before using in the lambda. As Lee pointed out though, I see no reason to be using a lambda at all in this case anyway.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Doesn't exist any perversion to use references with lambdas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, Oleg. Can you rephrase your question please?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185982/perversion-does-exist-any-way-to-natively-use-refences-with-lambdas-in-c#comment19663378_14185982

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure why you want to use a lambda here, it looks like you want:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\r\nBase string ({0} chars): {1}\r\nAfter RLE-encoding
            (
             {2} chars): {3}\r\nCompression percentage: {4}",
             str.Length, str, str_encoded.Length, str_encoded,
             (100 / str.Length) * (str.Length / str_encoded.Length)
            );
```

As the comment points out, you need to prefix the format string with an `@` since it spans multiple lines.

Comment: I think we'll also need to use the `@` prefix on the format string since it appears to be a multi-line string.

Comment: @lee, @ screening is needed only if you have two (\\) slashes in string or (\")

Comment: @OlegOrlov I'm not sure I understand your last comment... You _are_ talking about verbatim strings, right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx If your string is multi-line (in the souce code file, not because of \r\n escapes), you need the @ prefix.

Comment: @weston Good point, knew something was itching at the back of my head about mixing those two.

Comment: Never knew this. However, this breaks his `\r\n` as `\\` is no longer the start of an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lee, but when you really want to create a Lamba like this, and get its output you need to cast  explicitly something like:

```
(Func<int>)(() => (100 / str.Length) * (str.Length / str_encoded.Length)))();
```

I do this when I am playing with threads, not in production code though

Comment: Please correct your brackets. They are so many... And i assume, if you use lambda statement you must have `return` in your lambda.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thanks, had some misplaced. I corrected the code.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You do not need a `return` in the lambda; it is implied if the lambda has an expression that results in a value and is assigned to a delegate that indicates a return value (such as `Func<int>`)

Comment: In lambda expression not, but before correction there was lambda statement.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Ahh yeah, I see that in the edits; good pick up.

Answer (score 1):

String constants can be defined over multiple code lines with a `@` prefix, but then your `\r\n` will not work. So instead you can add string framgents together with `+` to achieve the same effect:

```
private static void EncodeString(ref string str)
{
    using (RLE inst_rle = new RLE())
    {
        string str_encoded = inst_rle.Encode(ref str);
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nBase string ({0} chars): {1}\r\nAfter RLE-encoding" +
        "(" +
         "{2} chars): {3}\r\nCompression percentage: {4}",
         str.Length, str, str_encoded.Length, str_encoded,
         () => { (100 / str.Length) * (str.Length / str_encoded.Length);}
        );
    }
}
```